# MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Increasing Battery Life

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, motherboard

Hi How to effective Battery charge in **MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)**.

As per my previous experience , i was using MacBook Air and i charge it 100 % and wait till drain then again Charge it. I used it two years, with in two years. Battery got damaged.I am worry about my new MacBook Pro.

My Doubts are-

1- Charge it 100% and wait upto 20 % and again charge full.

2- Charge 100% and Wait till it drain 1% and again charge it.

2- Always Charge MacBook Pro, when it is in use

3- How to increase Battery life of MacBook Pro

I have gone through it https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5689236?tstart=0 . but really not able to understand key points.

Please help me out to increase Battery life of my mac book pro

Comment: @Allan may be you thinking its duplicate but apart from battery draining , i have others question. in my doubts section. If you know something it does not means everyone know all things. please think and make duplicate as per user perspective. I know you have reputation to make Duplicate and i dont have that much reputation to cancel your power of making it duplicate.

Comment: @Allan answer suggested by you dont have proper and accepted answer. please check before making it duplicate